# Fastest way of evaluating a polynomial at a particular value

Tags: c++, c, math

What is the fastest known algorithm for evaluating a polynomial of a given degree, and known coefficients(in order)?
I tried to do it the following way:

```
long long int evaluatepoly(long long int* coeffa0,long long int degree,long long int x)
{
/*coeffa0 is the coeffecient array in order x^0,x^1,x^2....degree->degree of polynomial
  and x is the value where the polynomial is to be evaluated*/
  if(degree==1)
  {
    return (coeffa0[0] + (coeffa0[1])*x);
  }
  else if(degree==0)
    return coeffa0[0];
  else{
    long long int odd,even,n=degree;
    if(degree%2==0){
      odd=(n/2);
      even=(n/2)+1;
    }
    else{
      odd=(n+1)/2;
      even=(n+1)/2;
    }
    long long int oddcoeff[odd],evencoeff[even];
    int i=0;
    while(i<=degree)
    {
      if(i%2==0)
        evencoeff[i/2]=coeffa0[i];
      else
        oddcoeff[i/2]=coeffa0[i];
      i++;
    }
    int y=x*x;
    return (evaluatepoly(evencoeff,(even-1),y) + x*(evaluatepoly(oddcoeff,(odd-1),y)));
  }
}
```

I am a beginner so recommendations in improving the above code is also welcome(in C/C++).

Comment: fast or precise? Sometimes you cannot get both

Comment: One "common" way is to start with the coefficient for the highest degree, and then proceed by multiplying by `x` and adding the next coefficient: `res = a[n]; res = x * res + a[n - 1]; res = x * res + a[n - 2]; ... ; res = x * res + a[0];`. With this you have n multiplications and n additions.

Comment: This is the Horner's method right?....

Comment: I was going through a method called "Fast Fourier Transform". It mentioned to separate terms and follow a recursive method by separating the odd powers and even powers....

Comment: The answer to this will depend on much that you haven't specified: processor ISA, number of cores, number of evaluations, memory cache layout, and more.  And I'm not even sure whether the `long long` data type is what you really want.  Even if you [edit] your question to be more specific, I think you'll still end up with a lot of trial-and-measurement to hone the algorithm you choose.

Comment: The fastest way is `return 0;` - admittedly, you have to choose your inputs for it to be correct...

Comment: If you have a wide out-of-order processor, consider [Estrin's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrin%27s_scheme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your evaluation has recursive complexity

```
T(2n)=2*T(n)+2
```

if counting only multiplications, plus some overhead for the construction of the sub-arrays, resulting in overall T(n)=2n-2 multiplications (for n power of 2).

The (misnamed) Horner method uses n-1 multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple, relatively fast way to evaluate polynomials is by using the fact that you increment the exponent with each term:

```
int polynomial(int* coefs, int deg, int x) {
    int factor = 1, result = 0; 
    for(int term = 0; term <= deg; term++) {
        result += coefs[term] * factor;
        factor *= x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The above code has a linear time-complexity in the degree of the polynomial. Consider this pseudo-code, I haven't compiled it. Hope it helps!

[Faster](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69476/fast-evaluation-of-polynomials) methods exist, but are more complex.

Comment: In the code I mentioned in my question....won't the degree become halved every time I go through the function....thus reducing the time complexity?

Comment: @yobro97 The part of your code that splits the coefficients is O(n log n).

Comment: Oh...I forgot to include that in the time complexity...Thank you!!

Comment: Why keep factor around, you could do result = result * x + coefs[term], and do away with factor...